# GWT dev-mode external server class loader hell (Tough)

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, servlets, jetty

I have two eclipse projects (in the same workspace), one is a standard java project which runs a jetty instance. The other is a GWT project. The GWT project (on the filesystem) lives as a webapp in the java project and is loaded as such by the jetty (xml) configuration.

I run both through eclipse when debugging, first I start the jetty server as a regular java application (localhost:8080), and then the GWT project as a "Web Application (on external server)".

Everything works great except when trying to cast classes. In some circumstances I get java.lang.ClassCastException's. After hours of debugging I have determined this was due to two seperate class loaders being used, one from each.

I think this stems from objects that are created in a servlet context and those that are not.

I created a test to show this. Pretend the following method is called from an incoming request to a servlet, the argument instanceOfClassA created somewhere in the servlet request handler and passed to this method:

```
public void calledFromServlet(ClassA instanceOfClassA){

    ClassLoader systemClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    // systemClassLoader is sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@45a877

    Object classA1 = new ClassA();
    ClassLoader loader1 = classA1.getClass().getClassLoader();
    // loader1 is is WebAppClassLoader=GWTProject@b98fe1


    ClassLoader loader2 = instanceOfClassA.getClass().getClassLoader();
    // loader2 is sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@45a877

    ClientA request = (ClassA)instanceofClassA; // java.lang.ClassCastException!
}
```

As you can (hopefully) see, objects created in the current context, are loaded by WebAppClassLoader=GWTProject@b98fe1 and objects created (somewhere else) in the servlet context are loaded by the system loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@45a877.

Therefore when I try and cast an object which was created in the servlet context to LITERALLY the same class in the current context I get a ClassCastException.

Needless to say this is really ruining my week and I can't workaround the problem because I need to be able to cast objects.

Anyone experienced this before and have a solution?

**Update (Jan 5 2:24am):** I have tried forcing the class loader for the current thread using Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()). Still won't work.

**Update (Jan 6 1:09pm -- for Thomas Boyer)**

It appears that there is two threads of interest running, one which my breakpoint is on:

```
Thread [38] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 53 in CollaborationSocketListener))  
CollaborationSocketListener.onMessage(String) line: 53  
WebSocketConnectionRFC6455$WSFrameHandler.onFrame(byte, byte, Buffer) line: 845 
WebSocketParserRFC6455.parseNext() line: 359    
WebSocketServletConnectionRFC6455(WebSocketConnectionRFC6455).handle() line: 235    
SelectChannelEndPoint.handle() line: 606    
SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run() line: 46  
QueuedThreadPool.runJob(Runnable) line: 603 
QueuedThreadPool$3.run() line: 538  
Thread.run() line: 662
```

And the other one owned by the gwt-dev launcher:

```
 com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode at localhost:37240  
    Thread [main] (Running) 
Thread [Thread-0] (Running) 
Daemon Thread [Thread-1] (Running)  
Daemon Thread [UnitWriteThread] (Running)   
Daemon Thread [Timer-0] (Running)   
Daemon Thread [Code server listener] (Running)  
Daemon Thread [com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.base.internal.Finalizer] (Running)    
Daemon Thread [com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer] (Running)    
Daemon Thread [Code server for freshgwtp from Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686)     AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11 on http://localhost:8080/FreshGWTP.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 @ h`"*x.nukanE_ke_] (Running)
```

The method being called is in response to an incoming message to the servlet (WebSocket servelet). The relevant code is here:

```
public void onMessage(String serRequest) {

        // Create a request here to show that we can cast anything created in this context
    Object uFakeRequest = new ClientConnectRequest("someSite", new Client("SomeClient"));

    // This cast works fine
    ClientConnectRequest fakeRequest = (ClientConnectRequest)uFakeRequest;

            // Now I build the same object from a serialized object using a "deserializer" instantiated elsewhere (Note what it is instantiated does not seem to make a difference
    Object uRequest = streamer.fromString(serRequest);

            // ClassCastException
    ClientConnectRequest request = (ClientConnectRequest)uRequest;

    CollaborationSite site = siteManager.getOrCreateSite(request.getSiteID());

    site.onRequestRecieved(con, request);
}
```

The "streamer" is a gwt-streamer (See google code for details) and I have tried instantiating it in the servelet init(), as well as inline in this method, and by Guice injection. I always get the same class cast exception.

The reason being is that the streamer's class loader is the system class loader, and the class loader in this current method, is the GWT-Dev class loader.

** Update (Jan 5 2:36pm) More confusion **

In an attempt to seperate the conflict between the class loaders, I launched two seperate instances of eclipse, launched the jetty app in one and the gwt-dev mode (on external server) on the other. Still get the same error.

I don't understand why GWT thinks is should be handling class loading on the server side code of an external server...

Comment: Where are you doing those casts that throw exceptions? Can you give a full stacktrace for instance?

Comment: I added more details, thanks Thomas.

Comment: Where does GWT come into the picture? Isn't this a webapp classloader issue? In most classloaders, the child can read the parent's class instances, but that causes issues in webapps, so each is forced to be sandboxed. Both classloaders (root and GWTProject-specific) aren't the 'same', so their instances are different types. I think that leaving dev mode out of the picture will still see this issue happen, that it is entirely on the server, and further, this will likely happen on other servlet containers too.

Comment: The reason that I assumed that this was a GWT issue, was that it appeared that the GWT dev mode was taking over the class loading in some circumstances (When server side requests were being fufilled). I don't see how this would happen if I wasn't using gwt dev mode. That being said, I guess I won't rule it out, so if this is indeed not related to GWT, but is a general problem, how do I test or fix it?

Comment: So I found a workaround, by moving all my GWT server side code into my jetty app, and registering my servlet dynamically when jetty starts. This isn't really ideal, but at least I can keep working. Interestingly enough, the class loader "dump" which I outlined in my examples above are still the same. So I really have no idea why the problem disappeared. Would be great to know!